# exporting multiple functions but always run default function first

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry for the bad description but I would like to create a "service.js" -file where I export multiple functions that retrieve data from a database.
something like:

```
...
import Person from '../models/Person'
import dbConnect from "../lib/dbConnect";

await dbConnect()

const save = async (person) => {
    const savedPerson = await Person.save(person)
    return savedPerson
}

const geAll = async () => {
    const persons = await Person.find({})
    return persons
}
...

export default { getAll, save };
```

But how do I always run dbConnect() when the exported functions are used in the code ? do I need to add the await dbConnect() to every function or is there some smarter way to do this ?

Comment: Or you could make an object and on constructor call always `await dbConnect()`.

Comment: Just call `dbConnect()` when your main app component is mounting.

Answer (score 0):

What about a class with `await dbConnect()` on constructor? Something like:

```
class MyClass {
   constructor() {
     return (async () => {
        await dbConnect();
        return this; // new instance created
    })();
   }
   async save(person) {
      const savedPerson = await Person.save(person)
      return savedPerson
   }

    async geAll() {
      const persons = await Person.find({})
      return persons
    }

}
```

Then:

```
const myClass = await new MyClass(); // <-- this calls dbConnect()
myClass.geAll();
```